# How do I print out all keys in hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to learn how hashmaps work and I've been fiddling with a small phonebook program.

But I'm stumped at what to do when I want to print out all the keys.

here's my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.*;

public class MapTester
{

private HashMap<String, String> phoneBook;

public MapTester(){
   phoneBook = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public void enterNumber(String name, String number){
   phoneBook.put(name, number);
}

public void printAll(){
    //This is where I want to print all. I've been trying with iterator and foreach, but I can't get em to work
}

   public void lookUpNumber(String name){
    System.out.println(phoneBook.get(name));
}
}
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet--

Comment: phoneBook.keySet(); --> return a set of keys !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here we go:

```
System.out.println(phoneBook.keySet());
```

This will printout the set of keys in your Map using Set.toString() method. for example :

```
["a","b"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `keySet` from your `hashMap` and iterate it using e.g. a `foreach` loop. This way you're getting the `keys` which can then be used to get the `values` out of the map.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MapTester
{

    private HashMap<String, String> phoneBook;

    public MapTester()
    {
        phoneBook = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void enterNumber(String name, String number)
    {
        phoneBook.put(name, number);
    }

    public void printAll()
    {
        for (String variableName : phoneBook.keySet())
        {
            String variableKey = variableName;
            String variableValue = phoneBook.get(variableName);

            System.out.println("Name: " + variableKey);
            System.out.println("Number: " + variableValue);
        }
    }

    public void lookUpNumber(String name)
    {
        System.out.println(phoneBook.get(name));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MapTester tester = new MapTester();

        tester.enterNumber("A name", "A number");
        tester.enterNumber("Another name", "Another number");

        tester.printAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maps have a method called KeySet with all the keys.

```
 Set<K> keySet();
```